# Get and edit sub-list is in main list by java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have many main lists, and within it have a sub-list.
How to access the sub-list and edit it by java 8.

Example.

```
List<Student> list = ....; 
list[0]  = {id = 1, name = "aa", ListMinute = List<String> ls1}
list[1]  = {id = 2, name = "bb", ListMinute = List<String> ls2}
list[2]  = {id = 3, name = "cc", ListMinute = List<String> ls3}
list[3]  = {id = 4, name = "dd", ListMinute = List<String> ls4}
```

Example on sub-list of list[0] :

```
List<String> ls1 = {"120", "150", "45", "195"}; //List in minutes.
```

How to convert all sub-list from minutes to hours and minutes.
Output of sub-list of list[0] :

```
List<String> ls1 = {"2", "2.30", "0.45", "3.15"}; // List in hours and minutes.
```

Comment: Why are you storing minutes as string data?  Do you have to use lambdas here?

Comment: ..and by the way what kind of conversion results in 45/60 converting to 0.45?

Comment: This is data from old system, and I want to edit it.
I think on old ago, it's(string data) may be easy for display on web page(.jsp).

Comment: For "..and by the way what kind of conversion results in 45/60 converting to 0.45? "
Ans: yes.

Comment: use flatMap https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to get that converted could be :

---

```
List<String> ls1 = List.of("120", "150", "45", "195"); //List in minutes.
List<String> out = ls1.stream()
         .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
         .mapToObj(min -> String.format("%d.%d", min / 60, min % 60)) 
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
// would output 2.0 instead of 2 though
```

If you want to update your existing `List`, you can try `replaceAll`

```
List<String> ls1 = Stream.of("120", "150", "45", "195").collect(Collectors.toList()); //List in minutes.
ls1.replaceAll(a -> {
    int min = Integer.parseInt(a);
    return String.format("%d.%d", min / 60, min % 60);
});
```

Comment: Can I access it from main list?

Comment: @Javabeginer If you want to modify the same list, you can do a `replaceAll` as well. Update the same in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @nullpointer said, you can modify your `list` instance with `replaceAll` like

```
list.stream()
        .map(Student::getListMinute)
        .forEach(minutes ->
                minutes.replaceAll(min -> format("%d.%d", parseInt(min) / 60, parseInt(min) % 60))
        );
```